# Ubuntu 18 downgrade openjdk 8 version

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-18.04, downgrade

Hello I'm using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 and my java version is

openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)

I want to downgrade 1.8.0_275 to 1.8.0_265 how can ı do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a zip with the version you are looking,unzip the content and add the path to the bin folder in your PATH environment, here is a repo with the oldest you mention:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/tag/jdk8u265-b01

Also I'll recomend you to use https://sdkman.io/

[image: The 1.8.0_275 is still available in the AdopOpenJDK]

And if you download a version that loses support is still listed in your machine and you can change your version easily.

[image]